# Quicksort floats end up displaying only 0,00

Tags: c, quicksort

Disclaimer: some words in my program are in French.

I need to read a file that contains the student number, name, first name and grade of 118 students. Then use `quicksort()` to rearrange these students from highest to lowest grade. When I run my program suddenly every grade becomes `0,00` . I know there isn't any problem with my quicksort itself, the problem is with what concerns the variable `note` (grade). Anyone can help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_PERS 200
#define MAX_LONG_NP 15


typedef struct
{
    int numero;
    char nom[MAX_LONG_NP];
    char prenom[MAX_LONG_NP];
    float note;
}   donnees;

donnees tab[MAX_PERS];
int nbPers=0;



void lire(donnees tab[], int *n)
{
    FILE *aLire = fopen("notes.txt", "r");

    int nb=0;

    while(!feof(aLire))
    {
        fscanf(aLire, "%d%s%s%f\n", &tab[nb].numero, &tab[nb].nom, &tab[nb].prenom, &tab[nb].note);
        nb++;  
    }   
    fclose(aLire);
    *n = nb;   
}



void afficher(donnees tab[], int nb, char *quand)
{
    int i;

    printf("Contenu du tableau %s le tri\n\n", quand);

    for(i=0; i<nb; i++)
        printf( "%4d %15s %15s       %3.2f\n", tab[i].numero, tab[i].nom, tab[i].prenom, tab[i].note);
        printf("\n\n");
}



void echanger (donnees *P1, donnees *P2)
{ 
    donnees tempo;

    tempo = *P1 ;
    *P1 = *P2;
    *P2 = tempo;
}



void  partitionner ( donnees tab[], int debut, int fin, int *P )
{ 
    int G = debut , D = fin  ;

    float Val_Pivot = tab[debut].note;

    while ( G <= D  &&  tab[G].note >= Val_Pivot) G++;

    while ( tab[D].note < Val_Pivot) D--;

        if ( G < D ) echanger(&tab[G], &tab[D]);

    while ( G <= D ) ;

        echanger (&tab[debut], &tab[D]);

    *P = D ;
}



void quickSort ( donnees tab[], int gauche, int droite )
{ 
    int indPivot ;

    if (gauche < droite)
        {
            partitionner ( tab, gauche, droite, &indPivot);
            quickSort ( tab, gauche, indPivot - 1 );
            quickSort ( tab, indPivot + 1, droite);
        }
}




int main()
{
    donnees tab[MAX_PERS];

    lire(tab, &nbPers);

    afficher(tab, nbPers, "avant");

    quickSort(tab, 0, nbPers-1);

    afficher(tab, nbPers, "apres");



    return 0;
}
```

EDIT

These are the five first entries in the file:

```
1000 Docteur             Albert              65.5
1001 Solo                Hanz                23.4
1002 Caillou             Frederic            78.7
1003 Viky                Bryan               98.6
1004 Encas               Christian           67.7
```

These are the five first entries in the output :

```
1000 Docteur             Albert              0.00
1001 Solo                Hanz                0.00
1002 Caillou             Frederic            0.00
1003 Viky                Bryan               0.00
1004 Encas               Christian           0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

There *isn't* any problem with your quicksort for certain data sets, as evidenced by the fact I get the following output:

```
Contenu du tableau avant le tri

   1             pax          diablo       72.00
   2          george      washington       61.00
   3           bilbo         baggins       68.00


Contenu du tableau apres le tri

   1             pax          diablo       72.00
   3           bilbo         baggins       68.00
   2          george      washington       61.00
```

from the input:

```
1 pax diablo 72
2 george washington 61
3 bilbo baggins 68
```

Therefore, you may have some other problem *unrelated* to your code. I would suggest, at a minimum:

- posting a small version of your input file and the output it generates, assuming the problem doesn't go away when you reduce the input file;
- ensuring that the input file is *exactly* the correct format (four items per entry, and of the correct type), including no long names like "pax guido fortescue diablo".

---

However, one thing I *did* notice was this in your partitioning function:

```
while ( G <= D ) ;
    echanger (&tab[debut], &tab[D]);
```

That semi-colon at the end of the first line will result in an infinite loop under certain circumstances. I don't think that's your specific problem since that would result in *no* output of the sorted data but it's something you need to check once the first issue is fixed.

Even if you *do* remove that semi-colon, you'll find it won't help since you never change `G` of `D` in that loop. You need to therefore examine what is meant to happen to those variables when you swap the items.

Comment: I've edited my question to include a sample of the file and the output I get.